# What is a locally cosmall category relative to a universe?

Tags: ct.category-theory

What is a locally cosmall category relative to a universe?

Comment: I've never heard of the phrase 'cosmall'. What do you mean by this? Where did you hear it?

Comment: PS I edited the tags.

Comment: I have seen this concept in a paper of Enochs(see  section 7, of http://www.springerlink.com/content/9027521144483628/) in module theory where the author extends a module version of a theorem in general in a locally small and cosmall category relative to a Grothendieck universe. So the category of right modules over a unitary ring may be an example of a locally cosmall category!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is a clash of terminology: Some people call a category locally small if the hom-classes are sets. These people call a category well-powered if the subobjects of any object form a set; dually, co-well-powered refers to quotients. For these people, there is no notion of locally cosmall. Other people (and this seems to be the context of the question) call a category locally small if the subobjects of any object form a set (i.e. what the former call well-powered), and the dual notion concerning quotients locally cosmall (i.e. what the former call co-well-powered). For a reference, see Pareigis' "Categories and functors", Section 1.6. If you work with universes, replace "set" by "element of U" and "class" with "subset of U".

Comment: Dear Martin, thank you very much for your answer and  the reference.
I have seen this concept in a paper in module theory (cited in   comment, above). So the second definition of yours may be abut the subject.

Comment: Yes, Enochs also uses this terminology (locally cosmall = co-well-powered).

Comment: Good knowledge!  I hadn't heard this other usage of "locally small".  For what it's worth, some people prefer "well-copowered" to "co-well-powered": it's more logical, if you think about it...